# Unity sprites rendering problems on Android

Tags: unity, android, rendering, sprites

I'm creating a simple 2d game for android, with normal sprites and animations. The problem is that when I open the game on my smartphone (Samsung galaxy trend plus), The sprites are rendered this way:

[image: Bug]

Of course, this is not what should happen. Moreover, within the Unity editor everything works flawlessly. My settings for the export are:

- Texture compressions: ETC2 (GLES 3.0) - Tested also with "Don't override"
- Player settings

  - Default orientation: landscape
  - Use 32 bit display buffer: unchecked - tried also with this option checked
  - Rendering path: forward - tried also with Legacy Deferred
  - Static batching/Dynamic batching: both checked
- Camera settings

  - Clear flags: Solid color - tried also skybox

I don't have any other scene, and this one has only one camera (I saw some topics where people were having problems because they had two or more cameras). The sprites are all .png images with transparence, except for the background, that has no transparence, but is lagging. There are three sprites which are animated using the spritesheet, but they're terribly lagging, and almost can't be seen in this screenshot. I really can't understand why, I'll continue to try, waiting for your answers. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
If in the player settings the orientation is set to auto-rotate and the device is in portrait, all the sprites works perfectly!!! The problem is that my game is meant for landscape...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received an answer from the Unity Answers forum. It pointed out that I should've tried to disable the mipmaps on the sprites. After disabling them everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem 2nd time. I think it is a bug of Unity. Well, surprisingly the solution is out of the box. Solution is also like bug, silly bug silly solution.

Right now your camera is definitely at Z:-10 move it to -1.... something and change Clipping Planes to Near: 0.3 Far 3.

[image: Camera settings]

May be this exact solution may not resolve your problem, but solution does exist in this. Play with it if this exact settings not work.

**NOTE:** I hope your `Order in Layers` are properly set as the should be.

Comment: Thank you really much for such an immediate answer! I tried this exact solution, but it doesn't work for me. I'll try changing the values a little. I haven't touched the Order in Layer at all, but the background has a 'z' position of 2 so it should not be drawn above the other gameObjects, and the other objects are not overlaying.

Comment: Don't rely on Z if you are developing 2D. Consider `Order in Layers`. 0 is most behind then 1 is in front of 0 and so on...

Comment: And this solution did work for me when all the objects's Z is at 0 and sorted them through `Order in Layers`

Comment: I've just changed all the z value to 0 (there was only the background set), and to change the Order in Layers. Now the static images are working pretty well, but the animation and the background (which is static) not

Comment: I've changed the Order in Layer, so now there are no elements that has the same Order in Layer value of an other one. Still, the situation looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5T22brb7THEdFZZTlpiYWp4NEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Then I'd suggest to render your background on a Quad

Comment: Hi Hamza, first of all thank you for all the help. I've tried changing the Sprite with a Quad, but it's still giving me the same result. I've tried different shaders, but without any luck.

Comment: Did you set shader (Unlit/Texture) to the Quad?

Comment: Yes, I set that as the value and other 2/3 types. After I removed the quad and re-inserted the sprite it worked on that scene O.o ?!?!

Comment: :D.. Practice makes sprite work :D

Comment: Don't rely on editor.. Make a build and try it on device

Comment: That one yes, but the other are messed up XD I tried to apply the same settings to them, but it only differ in the size (1280x800 vs 1920x1080 - 1280 works). I'll try changing orthographic camera size to see if it improve something

Comment: I'm currently doing "Build and run" with my cellphone connected to the pc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35296/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-andrea-dragotta).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, then using the ordering of layers and changing the z value of the sprites to make them nearer or farther from the camera, it helped me.

Try making the objects closer to camera which as hidden or not seen clearly.

Hope this works.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Setting camera's clearflags to solid color solved this for me.